# How to set default value of a field in the end of create function

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

at the end of my create function I need to give `Amount_entered`the default value

```py
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
      .....
      .....
      ....
      vals['Amount_entered'] = default value????    
      return record
```

Comment: Did you called super() of this create function?

Comment: my problem is not with the create function, I called the super() but I need in the end to set the default value

Answer (score 4):

For default values you should use (this is correct and recommended way)

```
field_name = fields.Field(default=function/value)
```

In your case correct(correct but not recommended) code will look like this

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    vals['field'] = value
    record = super(module_name, self).create(vals)
    return record
```

or

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    record = super(module_name, self).create(vals)
    record.field = value
    return record
```